# Insert/Retrieve Date as per local time zone in MongoDB using Java

Tags: java, mongodb, date, timezone

I am inserting the current date in a mongodb collection using java.

I am using the following code to do so:

**BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("date",new Date());
coll.insert(doc);**

It is saving the date in GMT not in my local timezone.
But when I am inserting through shell using command:
**db.test.insert({date:Date()});**
It is taking my local timezone.

Is there any way to insert Date as per local time zone format using java
or any way to convert date to local timezone while retrieving.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: I would really recommend you to insert all dates as GMT. It will save you tons of trouble with daylight saving time and when your application will be deployed distributed on multiple timezones.

Comment: I agree with Philipp. To find the answer to your question, when I run insertion locally, I see that date is inserted in the format where deployed application resides(at least for me). Do you have your console and application server on different boxes?

Comment: No I am using the same system for both currently.

Answer (score 1):

The [java Date object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is intentionally timezone-agnostic and supposed to represent GMT times (it internally stores its value as milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT). I would really recommend you to work with this and internally handle all dates in GMT, because it saves you plenty of trouble with daylight saving time or when your application will be deployed in a distributed manner in multiple timezones.

To convert a Date object to or from strings representing it in the timezone of the user, use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) on which you called the [`setTimeZone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29) method with the users [`TimeZone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) (the static method [`TimeZone.getDefault()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault%28%29) gives you the time zone of the local system).